# Is there anyway to make a masonry / flexbox layout with a fixed width instead of height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, masonry

I'm wanting to put images across 3 columns. I want equal distance between the columns, however I want the heights to vary and be automatic to whatever height the image lands on from it's original height after being scaled in width. Is this possible to do with CSS on Chrome 116 / bootstrap 3 only?

I've tried looking up lots of codes for flexbox and masonry layouts. I see layouts that I want but when I look at the code, it says that I need to have a fixed height. I am wanting a fixed width instead of a fixed height, as all my images are different sizes and I want them to fit along the columns I make but then be staggered in height, letting the height be set automatically as I don't want the images to be warped.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve with laying out the images, the only difference is I want 3 columns instead of 4: https://www.homsweethom.com/work